# appending xml string to dom.documentElement

Tags: javascript, xml, dom

I have an xml string like the following:

var xml = `"<tests><test>90<test></tests>"`

I'd like to create elements from var xml and append this to dom.documentElement.

I've tried dom.documentElement(xml), but that throws an error.

```
uncaught exception: [Exception... "Could not convert JavaScript argument arg 0 [nsIDOMElement.appendChild]" nsresult: "0x80570009 (NS_ERROR_XPC_BAD_CONVERT_JS)"
```

How would I do this?

---

Here's some context.

I'm using the dom to manipulate xml elements.  The end output is to use XMLSerializer's serializeToString method and generate the final xml I'll be using to do REST calls.

Comment: Do you want to simply output "90" on the page? if so, use `document.write` then.

Comment: sorry, for some reason the editor stripped out my xml tags.  if the root element of the dom was <project>, then I'd like <tests> as its child, and <test> as its grandchild with 90 as the value...

Comment: k, but what html do you expect to have then? Do you want to use <tests> tag in html? If so then they'll be ignored because they're not  valid html tags. Please clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the DOMParser().

```
var p = new DOMParser();
dom.documentElement.appendChild(p.parseFromString(xml, "text/xml").documentElement);
```